# How to Make NSVisualEffectView That Only Appears When Content is Beneath It

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am working on a macOS application that makes use of NSVisualEffectView to achieve transparency. I want to achieve an effect similar to that of iOS' Cover Sheet widget view. Notice how when you scroll up, content a blur appears around the search bar. I want do this in a macOS app so that when content in a table view is scrolled beneath a certain point an NSVisualEffectView blurs it. How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a instance of Visual Effect View as following and set on window:

```
func setVisualEffectToWindow(window: NSWindow) {
        // create the visual effect view
var blurryView = NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600)) //Create with size you want or you can use window content bound here
    // this is default value but is here for clarity
    blurryView.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectBlendingMode.BehindWindow

    // set the background to always be the dark blur
    blurryView.material = NSVisualEffectMaterial.Dark

    // set it to always be blurry regardless of window state
    blurryView.state = NSVisualEffectState.Active

    window.contentView.addSubview(blurryView)
}
```

Comment: Does this ensure that the 'blur' will only be visible when content is beneath it? I have tried to create an NSVisualEffectView using Interface Builder, but since my application has a vibrant dark theme, the color of the NSVisualEffectView does not match the rest of the application.

Comment: Yes, if not work please share code snippet or something I can lookup

Comment: Thank you. I am attempting to do blending within the window, and the shade of the NSVisualEffectView is slightly off from the application's background. I am setting a vibrant dark theme on the window in its window controller, and I created the NSVisualEffectView in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

When using macOS 10.14 or newer, you can simply use the `headerView` material to have a blurry effect only when there is content beneath the effect view:

```
myEffectView.material = .headerView
```